# Check if request is coming from Swagger UI

Tags: python, request, fastapi, starlette

Using `Python` and `Starlette` or `FastAPI`, How can I know if the request is coming from the Swagger UI or anywhere else (Postman, Frontend app)?

I tried to see if there's something in `Request` object which I can use:

```
from fastapi import Request

@app.get("/")
async def root(request: Request):
    # request.client.host just returns some IP
    # request.headers doesn't contain any hint
    # request.scope ?
    request_from_swagger = request.hints_on_whether_request_is_coming_from_swagger_ui
    if request_from_swagger:
        return {"message": "Hello Swagger UI"}

    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

I need to take some actions based of that. So is there anyway I can tell, whether the request is coming from the Swagger UI?

Comment: Why don't you use the `Referer` key in the headers ? It will contain the url of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use the **referer** header of the request:

```
from fastapi import Request

@app.get("/")
async def root(request: Request):
    request_from_swagger = request.headers['referer'].endswith(app.docs_url)
    if request_from_swagger:
        return {"message": "Hello Swagger UI"}

    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```